# How can i do such query in multiple tables at the same time in django

Tags: django

I happen on some query like this below:

```
bphoto = B_Photo.objects.filter(q_user).order_by('-pub_date')
bactivity = B_Activity.objects.filter(q_user).order_by('-pub_date')
bpart = B_Part.objects.filter(q_user).order_by('-pub_date')
```

q_user is a Q object,and what i want is to sort all results in the three tables,use the 'pub_date' field.

how can i simplify this kind of query?

Comment: If two items have the same `pub_date`, who wins?

Comment: I don't know,maybe never they will be same? the default value is timezone.now()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B_Photo`, `B_Activity` and `B_Part` don't have the same table structure, right? I think you cannot make a query with three different table. UNION can do this but it requires all the sub-queries return data with the same structure.

It seems that you want to display a timeline mixed with photos, activities and parts. The most reasonable way is to sort the results in python.

```py
bphoto = B_Photo.objects.filter(q_user).order_by('-pub_date')
bactivity = B_Activity.objects.filter(q_user).order_by('-pub_date')
bpart = B_Part.objects.filter(q_user).order_by('-pub_date')

timeline = sorted(bphoto + bactivity + bpart, key=lambda x:x.pub_date)
```

UPDATE:

I see what you mean. If you have too much data in these 3 tables and you only want to show the most recent, say, 20 records, you can run a raw UNION sql on the 3 tables like this:

```py
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT id, type FROM (
    SELECT id, 'photo' AS type, pub_date FROM b_photo UNION 
    SELECT id, 'activity' AS type, pub_date FROM b_activity UNION 
    SELECT id, 'part' AS type, pub_date FROM b_part) AS my_query
    ORDER BY pub_date DESC LIMIT 20")
results = cursor.fetchall()
# results will be something like ((id, type), (id, type), ...)
# where type indicates what the id is (photo, activity or part)
```

Then use individual `B_XXX.objects.get(id=id)` to get each object in `ids`.

```py
for result in results:
    if result[1] == 'photo':
        obj = B_Photo.objects.get(id=result[0])
    elif result[1] == 'activity':
        obj = B_Activity.objects.get(id=result[0])
    elif result[1] == 'part':
        obj = B_Part.objects.get(id=result[0])
    # do sth with obj...
```

Comment: Whoops - beat me to it.  Just be sure to cast the querysets: `list(bphoto) + list(bactivity) + list(bpart)`. If this is too slow or too big, then you'll need to write the sql by hand as Django doesn't offer UNION queries across different tables.

Comment: in fact, i have an abstract base model class which include the 'user' and 'pub_date',B_Photo and other two are alias of the child class, can i use this feature instead of listing the queryset?